# jquery set class for a children of particular type

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-traversing

I have callout label associated with multiple controls, which should turn red when either of it is wrong.

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <asp:Label for="test">jquery will make my class as updnValidationErrorLabel</asp:Label>
    </th>
    <td > this text is right
        <asp:TextBox class='textboxWide taskListCheckPreVital' />
    </td>
    <td>this is wrong text hence it has updnValidationErrorInput
        <asp:TextBox class='dummyclass updnValidationErrorInput'/></td>

</tr>
​
```

I'm trying this approach, but not sure why mainparent children element does not show with class `updnValidationErrorInput`

```
//if my sturcture has updnValidationErrorInput
$('.updnValidationErrorInput').each(function() {
  // go to tr element
  var mainParent = $(this).parents('tr:first');
  // under tr element find updnValidationErrorInput
  if(mainParent.children('.updnValidationErrorInput').length > 0){
  // set label which has for attribute with    updnValidationErrorLabel
  mainParent.children('label').attr('for').removeClass().addClass('updnValidationErrorLabel');        
  }
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: -1 for badly formatted, unreadable code in the question.

Comment: But still cannot figure what are you trying to achieve here... :-\

Comment: Hi, Sorry for not able to conveying it properly.
I have label which is associated with two input controls.
I have similar structure through out the page.
My validator will set either of the input controls to updnValidationErrorInput class when something is wrong.
I m trying to make label associated with the input controls with 
updnValidationErrorLabel class when either of input is wrong. 
And common Label is determined if it is with in tr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're coming *from* the `<input>` the `.length` checks *must* be true, so you can remove them.  You can shorten it down to this overall:

```
$('.updnValidationErrorInput').each(function() {
   $(this).cloesest('tr').find('label[for]')
          .removeClass().addClass('updnValidationErrorLabel');
});
```

Instead of [`.parents('tr:first')`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) you can use the equivalent (and cheaper) [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), then find any `<label>` elements with `for=""` attribute and change the class on them.

Comment: Hi nick, what is the difference between `.parents()` & `closest()` ??

Comment: @Avinash - `.parents()` crawls all parents and *then* filters if given a selector, giving it a `:first` makes it get the first one since they're in the order of going up the DOM. `.closest()` crawls up the DOM and stops as soon as it finds a selector match, same result in this case, more efficient approach.  The more parents, the more savings with `.closest()`.